WSO2 Identity Server (wso2is-6.1.0) - ELK Integration Error
I am trying to integrate the ELK stack according to the below mentioned official documentation.
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.1.0/deploy/elk-analytics-installation-guide/
However, I am getting the below error during startup and in the Identity Server log and the server fails to startup.
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [log4j2] ERROR : Log4J2 configuration problem: No name attribute provided for Logger org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.logger.LoggerEventAdapter
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-log4j2 [org.ops4j.pax.logging.spi.support.EventAdminConfigurationNotifier] WARN : Sending Event Admin notification (configuration error) to org/ops4j/pax/logging/Configuration
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [log4j2] ERROR : Log4J2 configuration problem: No name attribute provided for Logger org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.logger.LoggerEventAdapter

I believe the issue is with the added log4j2 configurations but the name attribute seems to be already passed as per the doc.
logger.org-wso2-carbon-event.output-adapter-logger-LoggerEventAdapter.name=org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.logger.LoggerEventAdapter
logger.org-wso2-carbon-event.output-adapter-logger-LoggerEventAdapter.level=INFO
logger.org-wso2-carbon-event.output-adapter-logger-LoggerEventAdapter.appenderRef.CUSTOM_LOGFILE.ref=ANALYTICS_EVENT_LOGFILE

A direction to resolve this issue is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

There is a typo in the doc, replace org-wso2-carbon-event.output-adapter-logger-LoggerEventAdapter with org-wso2-carbon-event-output-adapter-logger-LoggerEventAdapter or anything else that does not contain a dot ..
